# symfony2 user management logs me out randomly

Tags: symfony

I have a user management interface built from fosUserBundle, and sometimes I get logged out after opening a user, it does not matter if I edit anything on this user, and save the changes, or if I just bring up the edit user form and then hit the back link, I still get logged out without any error or warnings in app_dev.php mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...and I realized that is what symfony2 does when you bring up a form to edit the currently logged-in user. If I am logged in as admin, and open the edit form for this user, the next route I go to (doesn't matter which one it is) will take me to the login page, bringing up the edit form for the currently logged-in user will log me out, no error or warning.

Thought it might be helpful to someone else who doesn't know that you can't edit the currently logged-in user.

I think it would be great if symfony2 threw an exception telling you that this is the reason for auto logout, at least in dev mode.

Comment: Maybe when you edit a user, FOSUserBundle will gave you the "identity" of that user. And if you update, yours (the user you edit) credential are old and so you have to log in again

Comment: So you open it and regardless you hit "save" or not, you are forced to log in again? sure that you have an "intermediate" action that will force you to log out?

Answer (score 1):

First you should check your logs in Apache.

I had a similar issue and it was caused by duplicate column name in one of the entities. All the other entities refused to work and it ended in being logged out every time I clicked something in admin.